# Net_SSH2 not working?

Tags: php, apache, authentication, ssh

I tried to add a registration thingy to my website and I tried to use net_ssh2 to do that, to add users to `.htpasswd` but whenever I run it, it just goes to a blank white screen. It does work however, if I remove all the ifs and if I don't assign a variable using the output of `$ssh->exec();`

here's my code:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('*******');
if (!$ssh->login('******', '*****')) {
    exit('Internal Server Error');
}

$cat = echo $ssh->exec("cat /etc/.htpasswd");
if (strpos($_POST["user"], $cat) !== false) {
    exit("User exists");
} elseif(strpos($_POST["user"], ';') !== false) {
    exit("Nice try..");
} else {
    $ssh->exec("sudo htpasswd -b /etc/.htpasswd {$_POST["user"]} {$_POST["password"]}");
    $ssh->exec('echo Complete; exit');
}
?>
```